# Shell. Can't redirect console output to file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that should redirect the application output from the console to a file.
If I write the following -

```
./ledToolz 2>&1 | grep 'Found' > panelVersion.txt
```

in the console everything is fine.
If I execute this from a script, nothing happens

Comment: It should work exactly the same. Are you in the directory containing `ledToolz` when you run the script?

Comment: Try using absolute paths so the script doesn't require you to be in a specific directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have both stderr and output displayed on the console and in your file use this:

```
./ledToolz 2>&1 | grep 'Found' | tee panelVersion.txt
```

@GendOS,
If you're trying to run the script on remote machine, you can do it like this:

```
USER="Your username"
PASSWD="Your password"
HOST="Your remote hostname"
SCRIPT_PATH="Path to your script"
sshpass -p $PASSWD ssh -l $USER $HOST 'bash -s' < $SCRIPT_PATH
```

Another option is copying the file first to the remote machine, execute it and remove the script on remote machine once you are done. It looks like this:

```
USER="Your username"
PASSWD="Your password"
HOST="Your remote hostname"
SCRIPT_PATH="Path to your script"

sshpass -p $PASSWD scp $SCRIPT_PATH $USER@$HOST:/tmp/script.sh
sshpass -p $PASSWD ssh $USER@$HOST /tmp/script.sh arg1 ar2 arg3
sshpass -p $PASSWD ssh $USER@$HOST rm /tmp/script.sh
```

Comment: I mean that if I start command directly from console, it’s  ok. But, if I start command from shell script, I have an empty file.

Comment: @GendOS Try specifying absolute path of "ledToolz" in your script if both ledToolz and your script that invokes ledToolz are not in the present working directory.

Comment: The script and the executable file are located in the same directory. I tried to specify the absolute path explicitly. Also doesn't write to file. It may be that I am calling a script on a remote machine from a local one. Like this sshpass -p 'passsword ssh admin@$1 'sh /home/admin/checkPanel.sh'

Comment: @GendOS, You can run the script on remote machine as shown above; updated the answer. Hope it should work this time. Good luck!